# TableLayoutPanel Height Property not working

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        TableLayoutPanel t = new TableLayoutPanel();  
        t.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
        t.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
        t.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(20, 150, 20, 20);
        lbl.Text = "Hello";
        t.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, 0);
        this.Text = t.Size.Height.ToString();
        this.Controls.Add(t);
```

Why the t.Size.Height property gives me 100 always ?

Comment: Avoid setting AutoSize to true if you don't like auto-sizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this always was returning 100 is that you need:

- `AutoSize = true`
- `AutoSizeMode =AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink`
- `t.RowCount >= 1`
- `t.ColumnCount >= 1`

  ```
      TableLayoutPanel t = new TableLayoutPanel();
      t.AutoSize = true;    //added
      t.AutoSizeMode =AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;    //added
      t.RowCount = 1;  //added
      t.ColumnCount = 1;   //added
      t.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
      t.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100));
      t.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;
      Label lbl = new Label();
      lbl.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(20, 150, 20, 20);
      lbl.Text = "Hello";
      t.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, 0);
      this.Controls.Add(t);
      this.Text = t.Size.Height.ToString();  //moved
  ```

You also need to move your Height check to after you have added the Table to the form, else no layout operations will have happened.